# Accessing Response Header in Angular JS -Laravel | JWT token

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, token, jwt

I am using Laravel as backend and JWT library (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth ) integrated in it. In the backend, on the every request the laravel responds with new token attached in response header like

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

here i am implementing front end in angular js Framework, and i intercept every request using a interceptor,

```
 angular.module('Authentication')
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor',['$cookieStore','$location',
 function($cookieStore,$location) {
   return {
        request: function(config) {
            var currenUser = $cookieStore.get("globals");
            if(currenUser) 
            {
                var token = currenUser.currentUser.token;
                if(token)
                {
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                }
            }else{
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            console.log(config);
            return config;
        } ,

        'response': function(response) {

            console.log(response.headers()); // no authorization header i get, 
            //but when i console, in the network i can see the authorization header token 
            //here i have to access the response header 
            //but i can't get authorization bearer from header 
            //if i get the value of token i can replace the currant cookie token value with this response token
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }


    }
}]);
```

php laravel 5.4 **web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {

    Route::get('profile', [
       'as' => 'auth.getAuthenticatedUser',
       'uses' => 'AuthController@getAuthenticatedUser'
    ]);

    Route::post('logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');

});
```

In first time the token is pass from **jwt library** in body part. It is stored in cookies, in the subsequent request the token passes via Header.

The server responds back to client with generated token via header,after that i have to replace the cookie token value.

Here is the problem i get, i can't access the response header information by the interceptor response. How can i achieve it? Any response is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide fiddle? because you should be able to do that.

Comment: *"on the every request the laravel responds with new token attached in response header"* <- that doesn't sound right at all. The bearer token should be negotiated between the client and server then used by the client in requests until the token expires

Comment: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication please check in the last section , i am used refresh token middileware, so in every request the authorization bearer responds with new token. @Phil

Comment: Ah, ok. A single-use token workflow

Comment: yes, could you please tell me how to access the header authorization in angular js? @Phil

Comment: So in your response interceptor, `console.log('Response auth header', response.headers('Authorization'))` doesn't yield anything?

Comment: nothing, i checkd it that also, on every request i consoled, there is no authorization header information, when postman responds nicely, and in the console networks, the headers received correctly. @Phil

Comment: Are these cross-domain requests (CORS)?

Comment: all are running in localhost now. means in same domain.But both are clearly separated, front end and back end. @Phil

Comment: Are the front and back ends running on separate ports or anything like that? I only ask as this looks exactly like your problem ~ https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/11#issuecomment-110681813. Maybe you need to configure the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` even if it's not cross-domain

Comment: yes! the laravel works in different port. and front end work in different port.

Comment: Different ports means requests are cross-domain. Seems you might have an answer now :)